# How do i apply a class to the body element after x seconds

Tags: php, session, timer

I am currently building a page (in php/wordpress), and I need the styling to change quite drastically after exactly 30 seconds, and then back again 30 seconds after that.

I know that I can set a session in php to run a check against, but this would only happen on page load.

Alternatively I could do it with javascript, but this would restart on every page load?

How could I get the best of both worlds, so that the timer starts when the user first visit the page, while allowing me to add a class to the body element after a specific amount if time?

I'm curious to hear how this could be approached.

Comment: Do this in js. 1st check for a cookie, if its **not** there, run the code (settimout) then set the cookie. This way it will only run once

Comment: Thanks for your comment. would you be able to go into more detail? maybe with code examples?